# Is there way to confirm user email when user change his email inside his profile - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-users

I have an option that allows a user to change email in his profile but without confirming a new email so when he enters a new email I want activate the email to save it in his profile, how to add confirm

- I am using UserCreationForm
- is there 3rd party app i can use it ? (my django version is 2.2)

models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

my code | forms.py :

```
# Profile Form
class EmailChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,label='Email',widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control center container','style': 'width:85%;text-align: center;background-color:#f6f6f6','placeholder':' Enter Your New E-mail '}) )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'email',
            ]
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count():          raise forms.ValidationError('Email is already in use, please check the email or use another email')
        return email
```

views.py :

```
# Edit Profile View
class EmailChange(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = EmailChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'user/commons/EmailChange.html'
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from blog_app.views import SignUpView, ProfileView, ActivateAccount,EmailChange

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/change-email/me/', EmailChange.as_view(), name='emailchange'),
]
```

html page :

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" style="background-color:#7952b3" value=" change ">
</form>
```

what is the next step will be to add activation when the user adds a new email?

Comment: Please do not assume your users' (and other programmers') gender. Many people on StackOverflow do not identify as males and your post might be perceived as offensive.

Comment: You will have to generate and save hash for user and have path that will have hash as argument and activate that user. There are various packages and some might have this implemented and you can look them up https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/authentication/. Recommendation of package is not https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @iklinac thanks a lot , do you know some resource explain this , i mean code